# Is there a function that will transform the values of an association while deleting some that match a criteria?

Tags: associations, filtering

I am looking for something better than

```
Select[Map[f,a],test]
```

As Map will work over the entire association (a) and then Select will work over all of the results. Something like

```
Cases[a,x_/;test[f[x]]:>f[x]]
```

But Cases only returns values (or functions of the values) not the keys.
I also tried

```
Map[If[test[#],#]&,a]
```

But it keeps the keys that fail the test and maps them to Null.

My sample association is

```
a = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5|>;
```

I would like to do something like

```
Select[Map[(3^#-2)&,a],PrimeQ]
```

Giving

```
<|b->7,d->79,e->241|>
```

My actual case is much more complicated but if I have a way to Map and Select in one pass for this case it will solve my more difficult problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you explicitly add what you would like the result of the operation to be? I.e. Show the association you would like to get in the end in your simple result.

Comment: You could perhaps make use of [AssociationMap](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationMap.html): it will map a function over an association like Map, but the function will be given the whole `key -> value` sequence as an argument. Alternatively, in your `If` attempt, you could explicitly return `Missing[]` when the test fails, then clean up the results by running `DeleteMissing` on the results, which will remove such `key -> Missing[]` entries from your association.

Comment: What is wrong with this? "Map will work over the entire association (a) and then Select will work over all of the results." Is it about memory efficiency? If you want to only build the result element by element, some contortion like `Reap[Do[If[test@f@Lookup[ass, x], Sow[x -> f@Lookup[ass, x]]], {x, 
     Keys@ass}]][[2, 1]] // Association` might help.

Comment: Also, +1 for `AssociationMap`. Occurrences of `Missing[]` will not clog the intermediate result too much either as they would all refer to a single instance of the object.

Comment: @TheVee, Yes, `AssociationMap` will work fine for my application.  I can map all of the delete cases to a single key-value pair that is easily and quickly removed (or ignored).

Answer (score 6):

The use of `AssociationMap` solves the problem in this case as it can map all of the deleted cases to a single key-value pair that is easily removed or ignored.

```
a = AssociationMap[If[PrimeQ[x = (3^#[[2]] - 2)], #[[1]] -> x, "XXX" -> 0] &, a]
```

giving

```
<|XXX->0,b->7,d->79,e->241|>
```

Then, if needed

```
KeyDropFrom[a, "XXX"]
```

giving

```
<|b->7,d->79,e->241|>
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You might want to use `Module` to localize the definition of `x` and avoid potential naming conflicts, i.e., `a = Module[{x}, AssociationMap[If[PrimeQ[x = (3^#[[2]] - 2)], #[[1]] -> x, "XXX" -> 0] &, a]]`

Comment: @JMM, `a = AssociationMap[If[PrimeQ[x = (3^#[[2]] - 2)], #[[1]] -> x, Nothing] &, a]`

Comment: @garej, Yes, nothing is better than Nothing!

Answer (score 3):

```
Association @ KeyValueMap[If[PrimeQ[3^#2 - 2], Nothing, #1 -> #2] &, a]
```

> `<|"b" -> 7, "d" -> 79, "e" -> 241|>`